# Pion $SU(2)$ representation with two light flavors of quark

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, pions

I am working through Srednicki's *Quantum Field Theory*.  I'm in chapter 94 and, perhaps I missed something, but I'm wondering how he arrived at a result.

He has the pion fields in his Lagrangian written as
$$\pi^aT^a\qquad(1)$$
This would be in $SU(2)$ and so when Srednicki later explains that $T^a=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^a$. I took that to mean the $\sigma^a$ here refers to the Pauli matrices.

Later in the chapter, however, Srednicki shows:
$$\pi^a\sigma^a=\begin{pmatrix}
\pi^0 & \sqrt{2}\pi^+\\
\sqrt{2}\pi^- & -\pi^0\\
\end{pmatrix}\qquad(2),$$
which is not what I'd expect if I did that sum over the index $a$ (which I presume runs from $1,2,3$ in order of the Pauli matrices).

Did I miss a detail?  Am I wrong in assuming $\sigma^a$ here refers to the Pauli matrices?  Is it that the $\pi^{\pm}$ here are actually combinations of two other fields?

Comment: Show your work: why wouldn't you expect that? You are adding three Pauli matrices with three coefficients, and then collecting the coefficients in the canonical $\pm$ definitions, linear combinations of $\pi^1$ and $\pi^2$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682482/identification-of-physical-pion-states-in-chiral-perturbation-theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the same thing rewritten in a different basis—the basis of charge eigenstates, rather than the $SU(2)$ eigenstates. The physical charged pion fields are complex linear combinations of the $a=1,2$ components of the isotriplet, $\pi^{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\pi^{1}\mp i\pi^{2})$. The other physical pion state, the neutral state, is $\pi^{0}=\pi^{3}$. Thus the expansion $\pi^{a}\sigma^{a}$ may be written
$$\pi^{a}\sigma^{a}=\pi^{1}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]+\pi^{2}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{array}\right]+\pi^{3}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right]\\
=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\pi^{3} & \pi^{1}-i\pi^{2} \\
\pi^{1}+i\pi^{2} & -\pi^{3}
\end{array}\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\pi^{0} & \sqrt{2}\pi^{+} \\
\sqrt{2}\pi^{-} & -\pi^{0}
\end{array}\right].$$
This is similar to the decomposition of the Pauli matrices in terms of $\sigma^{3}$ and the raising and lowering matrices $\sigma^{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma^{1}\pm i\sigma^{2}\right)$, which are
$$\sigma^{+}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right],\quad \sigma^{-}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: Thank you much.  I had an inkling it would be like that (similar to, if memory serves an earlier part in the book where this is done with complex scalar fields).  It's good to get confirmation.  Thank you again!